# Android 10: Android Q: NDK: opendir to /dev fails with errno 13: permission denied

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-10.0

In my android app I have written c++ (JNI/NDK) code to access (open/read/write) sound card device files (/dev/snd/pcmC*).
But, when running the app in a real device (Android phone), it fails with errno 13: permission denied.
I even tried to simply browse the /dev directory (passing "/dev" from Kotlin code in app),

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_amitabhs_myapplication_MainActivity_checkDevice(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject,  /* this */
    jstring name) {
result = "checkDevice: ";
struct pcm_params *params = NULL;
struct pcm_mask *m = NULL;
unsigned int min = 0;
unsigned int max = 0;
struct dirent *de = NULL;
DIR *dr = NULL;
const char *nameStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(name, 0);
dr = opendir(nameStr);
result += nameStr;
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(name, nameStr);
if (NULL == dr) {
    result += ": unable to open: ";
    result += std::to_string(errno);
    result += ": ";
    result += strerror(errno);
    return env->NewStringUTF(result.c_str());
}
...
```

This gives error "Error: unable to open: 13: permission denied".

In "AndroidManifest.xml", I have,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

In "CMakeLists.txt", I have,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
```

In "build.gradle", I have,

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.amitabhs.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

and

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        version "3.10.2"
    }
}
```

I have installed NDK (Side by Side) versions 21.1.6352462, 21.0.6113669, 20.0.5594570.
I have installed Cmake version, 3.10.2.4988404.
I have installed Android SDK Build-Tools 30 version 30.0.0.rc4, 30.0.0.rc2, 29.0.3.

I guess I am missing something in building the above code.

Not sure how the "tinyalsa" code was built and run successfully, as mentioned here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/tinyalsa/+/refs/heads/android10-mainline-release

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot access "/dev/snd/pcmC*" unless you have rooted the Android device.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, it seems I need to root my phone. Trying the same now.

Answer (score 0):

Before any read/write operation u should request for Permissions.Have you done that?.
This should be done from javaside ,using  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions

Comment: Just declaring permissions in manifest is not sufficient.u should Request for android run time permissions for reading and writing to storage using Java that shows prompt asking the user if the app can access storage once user accepts then u can read

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried requesting permission; didn't work. It prompts asking if app can access the storage. But, the "/dev" directory is not accessible.